# PL/pgSQL ERROR: too many parameters specified for RAISE

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I'm trying to put more than 2 parameters into a raise notice but i can't ¿How can i do it?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION TABLA_MULT(numeric) RETURNS void AS '
DECLARE 
texto1 TEXT := ''multiplicado por '';
texto2 TEXT := '' es igual a '';
BEGIN
RAISE NOTICE ''TABLA DE MULTIPLICAR DEL %'',$1;
RAISE NOTICE ''=========================='';
FOR i IN 1..10 LOOP
DECLARE result numeric := ($1*i);
BEGIN
RAISE NOTICE ''El número %'',i,texto1,$1,texto2,result;
END;
END LOOP;
END; ' LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

Comment: @Abra, this is PosgreSQL, not Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RAISE) you need one `%` for each parameter that should be replaced:

> The number of arguments must match the number of `%` placeholders in the format string, or an error is raised during the compilation of the function.

So you need:

```
RAISE NOTICE 'El número % % % % %',i,texto1,$1,texto2,result;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not specifically related to your question but you may want to investigate Postgres [Dollar-Quoted String Constants](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html). This relieves you from having to double quote within the function body. Thus your function (as initially posted by you becomes):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION TABLA_MULT(numeric) RETURNS void AS $$
DECLARE 
texto1 TEXT := 'multiplicado por ';
texto2 TEXT := ' es igual a ';
BEGIN
RAISE NOTICE 'TABLA DE MULTIPLICAR DEL %',$1;
RAISE NOTICE '==========================';
FOR i IN 1..10 LOOP
DECLARE result numeric := ($1*i);
BEGIN
RAISE NOTICE 'El número %',i,texto1,$1,texto2,result;
END;
END LOOP;
END; $$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

It would also be self beneficial to systematically indent your code.